# How do we calculate the cross section area and EMF in a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, magnetics, emf

**Case 1:** Consider an air core solenoid \$S_0\$ with inner diameter \$(d_{in0})\$ = 10 cm and the cross section area of the wire = 0.1 cm, outer dia \$(d_{out0})\$ = 10.1 cm. The number of turns in the solenoid is \$N_0\$ = 100 turns. There is 1 layer in the solenoid and all turns are one after another (long solenoid).

**Case 2:** Consider another air core solenoid \$S_1\$ with inner diameter \$(d_{in1})\$ = 10 cm and the cross section area of the wire = 0.1 cm, the number of turns in the solenoid is \$N_1\$ = 100 turns. There are 100 layers in the solenoid (each layer has exactly 1 turn) and all turns are one on top of another (a flat solenoid).

A N52 magnet is at a distance \$(R_{0})\$ = 100 cm from one of the faces of the solenoid and with instantaneous velocity \$(V_{0})\$ m/s towards the solenoid.

Faraday's Law says that for a tightly wound coil of wire, composed of N identical turns, each with the same \$\phi_B\$, the EMF produced is: \$EMF= -N(d\phi_B/dt)\$ where \$\phi_B\$ is the flux in a single turn.

**Query 1:** The above law is for an idealized solenoid. How do we calculate the cross section area and EMF in the two cases above? In the second case, do I assume 100 different solenoids each with a single turn but different radius and add the EMF to get the total EMF?

**Query 2:** How can the law hold for a long solenoid since some turns are further away from the magnet that others. How do we calculate in that case?

Please treat this question from the engineering perspective as well in the sense we are constructing a solenoid so things like an infinite ling solenoid won't help).

Is there any free and easy software that I can use (I don't have an electrical or electronics background). All I want it to input wire gauge, number of turns per layer, number of layers, and an N52 cylindrical magnet shape (length vs dia) and its distance and velocity from the coil to get an approximate EMF value?

Comment: Why are you constructing a solenoid? What are you hoping to achieve? What is the aim of this venture?

Comment: @Andyaka What I meant was if we were to construct a solenoid it should reflect real world scenario (hence the "..so things like an infinite ling solenoid won't help"). The objective is as follows: Since a moving magnet creates and induced EMF in coil, I want to figure out a shape of solenoid that with change in velocity as the magnet approaches the solenoid and passes though it does the following: (1) maximizes thermal losses and reduces the velocity of the setup (2) minimizes thermal losses and keeps as much velocity of the setup as possible.

Comment: I am reading with so many concepts for this approximation that i am struggling. i have seen many many videos of magnet travelling through a solenoid and slowing down but not one NOT ONE explains it mathematically. I am sure many people will benefit from it.. P.S. two setups are possible (1) Both can move horizontally (2) The coil is attached to ground and only a magnet can move..

Comment: A magnet will slow down when the solenoid is shorted or electrical power is extracted from it due to the magnet moving. Forget about technicalities, what are you hoping to demonstrate here. I ask because I smell an XY problem. What thermal losses do you refer to?

Comment: See in an AC induction heater the voltage oscillates. I want to know how much of an efficiency (which I define as thermal loss) we can achieve with a linear motion of a magnet through a coil. Thermal losses - Induced EMF generates a current in the coil, the current will oppose the source of EMF i.e. approaching magnet, but due to the current and resistance the wire would also heat up. This is what i refer to as thermal losses. I am assuming the coil and magnet both can move (Initially coil is at rest). That's it :)

Comment: Since the thermal loss will be dissipated in air (lets say the resistance doesn't change with the temperature of coil) the initial and final energy of the system would be different. Lets call that 'loss' as work. what is the best we can do..

Comment: can anyone please comment ??